# Angular Map with Map as value

Tags: angular, dictionary

I would like to use a `Map<string, Map<string, number>>` collection in angular.

Is this possible?

I have try to create a variable, init the variable, but when I try to set values it throws an error.

```
//define variable
public players: Map<string, Map<string, number>>;
...
//init map in constructor
this.players = new Map<string, Map<string, number>>();
...
//put some values in (throws error)
this.players['alphateam']['tommy'] = 7;
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, It's possible with using the set method
Example: `this.players.set('one',new Map<string,number>().set('one_one',1));`